# Authorize payments with Square API

Tags: node.js, square

Currently, I am creating payments with the Square API.
https://developer.squareup.com/explorer/square/payments-api/create-payment

This charges the customer's card for the desired amount. Is there a way to authorize a payment first without charging the card?

For our system, we need to wait a few minutes for a response from our vendor to process an order. I would like to authorize a payment, then if we get an approved response from our vendor, charge the customer's card otherwise cancel the payment.

I'm trying to avoid paying transaction fees, if we are unable to fulfill an order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `CreatePayment` (that you linked above) with `autocomplete` set to `false`. This will authorize the payment, but not actually take the funds out yet. By default, you have up to 6 days before the payment auto-voids, so you would want to call [CompletePayment](https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/payments-api/complete-payment) whenever you intend to complete the payment (or [CancelPayment](https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/payments-api/cancel-payment) if you want to manually void the payment).